# Can't add web reference for ebay API to a project(for web site it goes well)

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, ebay-api, vs-web-site-project

I' trying to add web reference for ebay api following this guidance: 
 http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/HowTo/FirstCall/MakingCallCSharp.html
I added the web reference executing following steps:

> Right-click References -> Add Service Reference -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference -> Enter URL -> Add Reference.

Reference added, but there's something wrong with it. I have the same reference in Web Forms Web Site, I tried to reload reference executing the same steps, and it goes well, here is the picture of how it looks in solution explorer :

[image]

When I try to add the same reference to MVC version of this project there's how this reference looks:

[image]

As result I can't acces all members declared in this libraries.

> I found that creating new projects I'm getting the same error, BUT when I create new Web Site, it goes well. Does anybody know what are the differences between adding web reference to projects and to Web Sites?